Is this a non-standard extension?
I started reading Henson's "Foundations of Nonstandard Analysis. A Gentle Introduction to Nonstandard Extensions" a couple of days ago, and I am a bit confused about something.
Let $F$ be an ultrafilter in $\mathbb{N}$, and for any $X$ denote by $\prod_FX$ the ultraproduct of $X$ along $F$.
I think (?) we have a non-standard extension $(^*\mathbb{N},^*\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ of $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ given by $^*\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}$ and $^*\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})=\prod_F\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, given by, to any subset $O$ of $\mathbb{N}^k\times \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^l$, we associate the set of points $(n_1,\dots,n_k,(A_{1,i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}},\dots,(A_{l,i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}})$ such that for $\mathcal{F}$-almost every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $(n_1,\dots,n_k,A_{1,i},\dots,A_{l,i})\in O$.
However, this seems not to be isomorphic to a nonstandard extension of $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ as the one mentioned in Remark 5.1 of the book (see the remark in the figure), at least via the isomorphism given in the justification of the remark.

In the remark they tell us to define a map $\Phi:^*\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by
$$\Phi((Y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}})=\{h(x);x\in\mathbb{N}\text{ and }x\in Y_i\text{ for $F$-almost all $i\in\mathbb{N}$}\}.$$
And they say that $\Phi$ is injective. But it is not injective, as it seems the image of the standard elements of $^*\mathcal{P}(X)$ by the map $\Phi$ is already all of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.
I must be missing something; thanks to anyone who can help clarify this.

I think you may have misidentified the range of $\Phi$.  Understanding what's involved requires going back to Remark 2.10, as mentioned there.  I think all is all Goldblatt's text may be a better introduction.

Thanks, I will check Goldblatt's textbook. But I don't think I have misidentified the range of $\Phi$. I am just taking $\mathbb{Y}=^*\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}$, with the bijection $h:X\to\mathbb{Y}$ being the identity

Morally, ${}^\mathcal P(X)$ has "too many sets" because only the elements of ${}^\mathbb N = \mathbb N$ are "witnessed", so it has get mapped down to $\mathcal P(X)$. This makes me think that Henson's (implicit) notion of "isomorphism" is incorrect, and we really only want ${}^E$ mapped bijectively but not necessarily ${}^\mathcal P(X)$.

What do you mean by $\mathbb{Y}=^*\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}$ ?

@MikhailKatz I have defined the extension $^\mathbb{N}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ to be just $\mathbb{N}$ (the "trivial non-standard extension", I guess). So the set $\mathbb{Y}$ from Remark 5.1 can just be taken to be $\mathbb{Y}=\mathbb{N}$, with the bijection $h:^\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Y}$ being the identity. This satisfies the conditions of Remark 2.10.

@NicholasTodoroff Thanks for the answer. If that is the case then there would not be much more to add, as it is just a problem with that remark of the book (perhaps his initial definition of non-standard extension of $(X,\mathcal{P}(X))$ is too broad)

There is some sort of issue here... apply Transfer to $$\forall Y,Y'\in\mathcal P(X).:[\forall x\in X.:(x,Y)\in E\iff(x,Y')\in E]\iff Y=Y'.$$ This proves Henson's assertion that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism. So I would agree it's probably something about the definition of a nonstandard extension. I would first check meticulously, axiom-by-axiom, that your $*$ is in fact a nonstandard extension by Henson's definition.

I will check that again tomorrow, I must have missed something (that is why I named the question as I did). I was also thinking of reading Goldblatt's book (which is slower paced), as @MikhailKatz suggested
